# Is there a way to beautify the styles of a webserver generated directory listing?

Tags: apache, iis, webserver

Now and then we need to show the contents of a webserver directory (mostly IIS, sometimes Apache). Problem is, it looks ugly (arguably).

Of course we could use a .NET (or php) script that reproduces the functionality.

But is there a direct way to influence the look of the listing or change the style sheet somehow? Can I add a CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that in IIS 7+ you can [use your own module to define the look and feel](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/01/21/Get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-IIS-website-with-DirectoryListingModule.aspx).

When [searching Google for the `DirectoryListingModule`](http://www.google.de/search?q=directorylistingmodule%20iis7) you find nice gems like the [Image Gallery Directory Listing Module](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1325).

Answer (score 2):

In apache, you just add stuff to an `.htaccess` file. [Here](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/11/02/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) is a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know. Now I just wish something similar was possible in IIS.